# Using both API Key & Basic Auth in Python or Postman

Tags: python, api, python-requests, postman

I have an API end-point that I have been given an API key for, but it also looks to have basic auth in front of it.

Can someone explain how I can use both basic Auth and an apiKey with Postman, or requests in python?

When I use the authentication section in Postman it will only let me pick one or the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python:

```
import requests

url = 'apiendpoint'
api_key = 'api-key'
username = 'username'
password = 'password'

session = requests.Session()
session.auth = (username, password)
session.headers['X-API-Key'] = api_key
response = session.get(url)
```

Postman:

In Postman, go to the "Authorization" tab in the request builder.

Select "Basic Auth" from the "Type" dropdown and enter your username and password for Basic Authentication.

[Authentication Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VV9PJ.png)

for Api-Key go to Headers tab next to Authorization tab and enter 'X-API-key' in key section and your api key in value.

For generate basic authentication using base64 click on link [Basic Authentication Header Generator](https://mixedanalytics.com/tools/basic-authentication-generator/)

Comment: This actually doesnt seem to work. I need to pass the api-key in at the end of the url: "&apiKey=my_api_key". Any idea what the problem could be?